UnsupportedOperationException in LogbookHttpRequestInterceptor with Spring Boot 3.2.2 and Apache Http Client 5 (how to fix test?)
I Upgraded Spring Boot (was 3.1.9, became 3.2.2)
At the same time, the spring-web version increased (it was 6.0.17, became 6.1.3)
After that, the test works with errors
test
This test calls method "customize":
customize
where
vars
MdcService - we have written an interface "MdcService" that defines the filling of MdcContext
Test throws an error (part of the stacktrace is given below):
stacktrace
If you replace with restClient in the restTemplate test and make the call as to restClient, then the test will end with the same errors
(val restClient = RestClient.builder(restTemplate).build())
Version used:
Logbook: 3.5.0
Spring Boot: 3.2.2
spring-web: 6.1.3
I found an explanation for these errors: https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/1693
This is because HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest has been reworked in Spring Framework 6.1.
There is also a link ( https://github.com/zalando/logbook/pull/1701 ) and says:
Use writeTo() to buffer HttpEntity in httpclient5
Use HttpEntity.writeTo() instead of relying on EntityUtils.toByteArray() to copy the OutputStream of the HttpEntity.
Thus, for test is necessary to replace EntityUtils.toByteArray() with HttpEntity.writeTo()
But how to do this if EntityUtils.toByteArray () is deep in stacktrace
How to fix the test?

I solved this problem by replacing the versions of the logbook libraries (it was: 3.5.0, it became: 3.8.0)
